# Swift 3 / How to handle nested NSDictionaries since "Value of type Any has no member value"

Tags: ios, swift

*Please dont' mark as duplicate of "Value of type Any has no member value". I'm not asking how to solve the compiler error.*

My **question** is: What is the best practise to handle nested Dictionaries with the new need to downcast everything?

My code in Swift 2 was:

```
if result != nil {

    let token = String((result.value(forKey: "credentials")?.value(forKey: "token"))!)
    let uid =  String((result.value(forKey: "uid"))!)
    let bio = String((result.value(forKey: "extra")?.value(forKey: "raw_info")?.value(forKey: "data")?.value(forKey: "bio"))!)
    let followed_by = String((result.value(forKey: "extra")?.value(forKey: "raw_info")?.value(forKey: "data")?.value(forKey: "counts")?.value(forKey: "followed_by"))!)
    let follows = String((result.value(forKey: "extra")?.value(forKey: "raw_info")?.value(forKey: "data")?.value(forKey: "counts")?.value(forKey: "follows"))!)
    let media = String((result.value(forKey: "extra")?.value(forKey: "raw_info")?.value(forKey: "data")?.value(forKey: "counts")?.value(forKey: "media"))!)
    let username = String((result.value(forKey: "user_info")?.value(forKey: "username"))!)
    let image = String((result.value(forKey: "user_info")?.value(forKey: "image"))!)

    self.saveAccount(token, uid: uid, bio: bio, followed_by: followed_by, follows: follows, media: media, username: username, image: image)

}
```

**I know that the error appears because I need to downcast since Swift 3.**

But since I'm querying a nested Dictionary, every single step needs to be downcasted as `AnyObject` and within 10 lines of code I cast `as AnyObject` like 50 times. And some lines are like 1 Billion characters long...

```
if result != nil {

    let token = String(describing: (((result as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "credentials") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "token"))!)
    let uid =  String(describing: ((result as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "uid"))!)
    let bio = String(describing: (((((result as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "extra") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "raw_info") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "data") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "bio"))!)
    let followed_by = String(describing: ((((((result as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "extra") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "raw_info") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "data") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "counts") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "followed_by"))!)
    let follows = String(describing: ((((((result as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "extra") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "raw_info") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "data") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "counts") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "follows"))!)
    let media = String(describing: ((((((result as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "extra") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "raw_info") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "data") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "counts") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "media"))!)
    let username = String(describing: (((result as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "user_info") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "username"))!)
    let image = String(describing: (((result as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "user_info") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "image"))!)

    self.saveAccount(token, uid: uid, bio: bio, followed_by: followed_by, follows: follows, media: media, username: username, image: image)

}
```

For example `let followed_by`

```
let followed_by = 
String(describing: ((((((result as! NSDictionary)
.value(forKey: "extra") as AnyObject)
.value(forKey: "raw_info") as AnyObject)
.value(forKey: "data") as AnyObject)
.value(forKey: "counts") as AnyObject)
.value(forKey: "followed_by"))!)
```

I have another function where I query for 25+ objects and downcast like 100 times....

I know how to get the result, but is there a more advanced way to handle this scenario? Or at least to have it appear more readable? Help is very appreciated.

PS: It doesn't makes any difference if downcasted as `NSDictionary` or `AnyObject`, but since I know *what* I'm downcasting, I prefer to cast it as `NSDictionary` over `AnyObject`.

Comment: Why not start with `let resultDict = result as! NSDictionary; let token = resultDict.value(forKey: "credentials") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "token"))!);` and so on, at each level. Or why not converting them into custom objects with properties and stuff by serialization?

Comment: I have used `let resultDict = result as! NSDictionary` before I have opened this thread. But it still didn't seemed to save too much code

Comment: `Or why not converting them into custom objects with properties and stuff by serialization?` what do you mean by that?

Comment: I'd have a class `Credentials`, a class `Extra`, a class `Data` (well, not data, since it's already a class, but DataCustom) and `User`. If you have some Objective-C notions, here a suggestion: http://pastebin.com/DvCtqER8 (done only for the example of User), and you just declare resultDict as Dictionary, and then call the `iniWithJSONDict:`: ATopLevelResponse *myTopLevelObject = [[ATopLevelResponse alloc] initWithSONDict:resultDict]; (I called JSON, because I guessed that was a JSON). Then to retrieve the user Name: `let username = myTopLevelObject.user.userName`

Comment: As always: **Do not use `valueForKey`** unless you know what KVC is and what it does. In Swift use key subscription `object["key"]`

Comment: those are the advanced tips i was hoping for. thank you guys.

Comment: @Larme I'm not good with ObjC, but I kinda get your tipp and I will try to translate its logic to swift

Comment: @vadian okay. never anyone told me not to use valueForKey. So i should use `item["key"]`? could you be more specific about the disadvantages or provide any documents that i can consider? please

Comment: @vadian , reading this right now: http://blog.shiftybit.net/2015/07/kvc-in-swift/

Comment: `valueForKey` is a special key-value coding method providing for example accessing properties by key path in Cocoa classes. It's unnecessarily expensive to use it for simply accessing values for keys in dictionaries.

Comment: Yes, but `dictionary["key"]` is **not** KVC

Comment: but that was the point, wasn't it? to use `dictionary["key"]` instead of `valueForKey` to bypass KVC

Comment: Yes, always use key subscription unless you really need KVC.

Comment: @vadian I was able to translate your code into swift and I'm testing it right now, but it seems to be, what I was looking for. impossible to have the code be even shorter. if you dont mind, take the time and answer, so i can upvote

Comment: thank you @vadian since that also answers my question, please take a minute and answer, so i can upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all and second **Do not**: Do not use `NSDictionary` in Swift. You throw away the type information.

And yes, you have to downcast the intermediate objects but always to something the compiler can safely work with (Swift `Dictionary` or `Array`).

Since all intermediate objects are obviously dictionaries cast them to `[String:Any]`.

Here is a short example. For clarity a type alias for `[String:Any]` is used.

```
typealias JSONDictionary = [String:Any]
```

This extracts the objects in the `extra` node

```
if let result = result as? JSONDictionary  {

  let token = (result["credentials"] as! JSONDictionary)["token"] as! String
  let uid = result["uid"] as! String

  if let extra = result["extra"] as? JSONDictionary,
    let rawInfo = extra ["raw_info"] as? JSONDictionary,
    let data = rawInfo["data"] as? JSONDictionary {

    let bio = data["bio"] as! String

    if let counts = data["counts"] as! JSONDictionary{
      let followed_by = counts["followed_by"] as! String
      let follows = counts["follows"] as! String
      let media = counts["media"] as! String 
    }
  }
}
```

Of course this code is not tested but you get an impression how to parse nested dictionaries. If `result` is deserialized JSON consider to use a library like SwiftyJSON.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, help and explanation

Comment: i have tried every provided solution now and yours is by far the best for my needs. it's simple and i'm very thankful for the explanation. honeslty, i thought that the solution of @Larme was the best, creating classes and everything. But in the end it was like 100 lines more code, even tho the result was easy readable.

Comment: than you for all the explanations and tipps

Answer (score 3):

I guess the rationale there is that Swift tries to err on the side of certainty which makes dealing with NSDictionary data a little bit trickier.

It's hard to optimize not seeing the actual structure of 'result', but here's an attempt:

Assuming a data structure similar to:

```
let result = [
    "credentials": [
        "token": "token"
    ],
    "uid": "uid",
    "extra": [
        "raw_info": [
            "data": [
                "bio": "bio",
                "counts": [
                    "followed_by": 100,
                    "follows": 100,
                    "media": 100
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "user_info": [
        "username": "username",
        "image": "image"
    ]
] as [String : Any]
```

This code can "parse" it into variables (tested in a playground):

```
if let result = result as? [String : Any] {
    let token = (result["credentials"] as! [String:String])["token"]
    let uid = result["uid"]
    let data = (((result["extra"] as! [String : Any])["raw_info"] as! [String : Any])["data"] as! [String : Any])
    let bio = data["bio"] as! String

    let counts = data["counts"] as! [String:Int]
    let followed_by = counts["followed_by"]
    let follows = counts["follows"]
    let media = counts["media"]

    let userInfo = result["user_info"] as! [String : String]
    let username = userInfo["username"]
    let image = userInfo["image"]

    // ...
}
```

The code could have been even more concise, had the structure of "extra" been known.

Comment: thank you for your input!. i havent posted the json struct, because it is way more complex and one would just lose the overview

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing this is almost impossible to read, but also this is not how you use dictionaries in swift.

Is there a reason you are using NSDictionaries and value(forKey: ) instead of switching over to swift Dictionaries with Dictionary (swift 3 style guide wants us to type this as [String: AnyObect]) ? Are you trying to access the value(forKey: ) features of NSDictionary or just trying to get the value of result["uuid"]?

What I would do is create models or structs for each of those nested dictionaries. (Is this a JSON response?)

If I'm reading it correctly, followed_by is a variable within a nested dictionary(not sure if that is right)? So for instance- and this is one of the deeper nested dictionaries, but you could work your way up with this- You would create a class called "Counts"

That class would have properties, in your case those properties would be something like: followedBy(array of users?- users would also probably have custom class with properties like userName and image), follows(array of users?), media(whatever type of object this is)- and those properties would be initialized by that dictionary. So init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]).

```
if let followersDictArray = dictionary["followed_by"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
  var followers = Array<UserModel>()
  for followersDict = followersDictArray {
    if let follower = UserModel(dictionary: followersDict) {
    followers.append(follower)
    }
  }
  followedBy = followers
}
```

And continue like that with the rest of the properties.

You would have a class called Data with properties like bio(idk what type this is, but assuming String?) and counts(which would be of object type Counts.init(dictionary: ) and that Data class would be initialized by a dictionary which would hand the information to those properties.

You would work your way up like that to parse the data.

Essentially, you want structs or classes for nested dictionaries. You would NOT want to be doing all of that as! AnyObject stuff. The second you start seeing all of those exclamation points and ((((( while trying to access information from your JSON dictionary, you should take it as an alert that you are doing something very wrong.

In doing this the way you are doing it - you are not protecting yourself against JSON response errors and others will not be able to read your code.

Additionally, you should never be using snake case for a swift variable name.
followed_by should be followedBy

Comment: I just want to reiterate - you should almost never have any ! while getting data from a JSON response. Your app will crash if anything is wrong with that response.

Comment: thank you very much for your input. to the `snake case`, i know about that, it was just build naming copying the `["value"]`to not lose the overview

Comment: @DavidSeek gotchya! let me know if you have any more questions along the way while trying to access the dictionaries and initialize object models. It will take a bunch of reorganization in the beginning, but will make your code significantly more efficient/readable and easier to troubleshoot.